# AngularJS - Set promise manually

Tags: angularjs, promise

In `AngularJS`we work a lot with promises, and I was wondering if there is some way to manually set the result of promise (whether it was a success or not) manually without `reject` and `resolve`

Something like

```
var list = [];

function call(){
    async()
       .then(function(response){
            console.info('yay');
       })
       .catch(function(error){
            console.info('nay');
       });
}

function async(){
   var item = {
       id: 1,
       defer: $q.defer()
   };

   list.push(item);

   sendRequestToAsyncService(item.id);

   return item.defer.promise;
}

function receiveDataFromAsyncService(data, id){
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        if(id === list[i].id){
             list[i].defer.promise = data;
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: What does set it manually mean if you aren't going to use the manual methods `resolve` and `reject`? What is the higher level problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling for a while I found the answer, I had to use the resolve/reject functions at the defer root level.

```
list[i].defer.resolve(response);
```